# Getting the result from execute_async_script()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to store the result of the script with `execute_async_script()` but it always returns `None`

```
print(driver.execute_async_script("""
var done = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
x=confirm("yes or no");
arguments=x;
done();
"""))
```

> the confirm window is treated by the user but the selenium webdriver doesn't wait for the input and returns `None`

Comment: I think you should `return` from script block.

Comment: the selenium driver doesn't wait for the user to click the button and returns  `None` @sardok

Comment: ok, can you try `execute_script` then?

Comment: @sardok same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with Selenium where `confirm` causes `driver.execute_async_script` to exit early and return no value. [Here is the relevant issue on the Selenium repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10026).

To get round this you could use a form with event handlers in place of the `confirm`. Call the final element in arguments in the resolution of the form submission handler to make the execution wait until the user has selected an option. You need to pass the data you want back to the `done` callback instead of setting `arguments` to it. The following code is a full program example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

# Get an instance of webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Load an HTML form instead of using the 'confirm' popup window
driver.get("""data: text/html,
<form>
    <h1>yes or no</h1>
    <input type="button" id="okButton" value="OK">
    <input type="button" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel">
</form>
""")

# Run the script and wait for the result
print(driver.execute_async_script("""
var done = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
document.getElementById("okButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // OK button clicked
    done(true);
    // We no longer need the event handler
    this.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee);
});
document.getElementById("cancelButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Cancel button clicked
    done(false);
    // We no longer need the event handler
    this.removeEventListener("click", arguments.callee);
});
"""))
```